# How can you automatically select a listcell when one of its internal components receives focus?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a javafx listview where each listcell contains a graphic with several nodes. One of those nodes is a Textfield. When a textfield is given focus (the user clicks on it), I would like the listcell it's located in to also get selected. I haven't been able to find a general way to achieve this in javafx.

I am able to achieve what I want by hard-coding in a way to get all the information needed to select the item I want, but I would like to avoid this if there is a better way. Below is what I needed to do in my more complex app...

Parent skin = this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();

int index = skin.getParent().getChildrenUnmodifiable().indexOf(skin);

ListView listview = (ListView) 
skin.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();

listview.getSelectionModel().select(index);

Here's a simple app that hopefully illustrates the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```java
    package uitesting;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
    import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class testSelection extends Application {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
            ListView<String> viewer = new ListView<>();
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(viewer,5D);AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(viewer,5D);
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(viewer,5D);AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(viewer,5D);
            pane.getChildren().add(viewer); // Add listview to root pane
            ObservableList<String> viewItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    "Lorem Ipsum",
                    "I would like the cell this is located in to get selected when this text is clicked while the cell is not selected.",
                    "A third listcell");
            viewer.setItems(viewItems);
            // Modify the cell factory
            viewer.setCellFactory((e)->new myListCell());
            // create and start the stage
            primaryStage.setTitle("Test GUI");
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 600, 300));
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        static VBox createGraphic(String text){
            // Put together an example pane with a button and a textfield that will go into each listcell
            Button buttonA = new Button("A Button");
            TextField textField = new TextField(text);
            textField.setEditable(false);
            VBox root = new VBox();
            root.getChildren().addAll(buttonA,textField);
            return root;
        }
    }
    class myListCell extends ListCell<String>{
        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(testSelection.createGraphic(item));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a very odd way of populating a `ListView`. Is there a reason you aren't using a `CellFactory` instead?

Comment: No, I just wrote it that way because it was quick and it works for me. I don't think that would make a difference though for my question, would it? If it does, I can edit the example.

Comment: One should avoid using `Node` as the element type of a `ListView`; the element type should be the model object which should have no knowledge of the view. Instead, when complex visuals are needed, set the `cellFactory` and return a custom `ListCell` that builds and uses (and reuses) the necessary GUI object as the `graphic` of the cell. Doing it this way will also give you access to the `ListCell` which makes it much easier to select it via the selection model.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I appreciate the feedback. I'm self-taught so I'm not always aware of details like that. I've edited the code to use a custom listcell based on your suggestions.

Comment: unrelated: _don't_ create the graphic each time updateItem is called, instead create it once at instantiation time and configure in updateItem

Comment: to your requirement: basically, your listCell needs to register a changeListener to the scene's focusOwner property (once it is available), on receiving change notification check whether the new owner is a child of the cell and if so change the listView's selection state

Comment: Interesting, could you elaborate on how you would check if the new owner is a child of the cell?